# Can't get json result on my phonegap page

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to get some json data in my application, but it won't come in the result function.

```
function myLoad(){  
        output.innerHTML = 'in the load';// + items;
        var myJsonUrl = 'http://....be/.../lineup.php';

        $.getJSON(myJsonUrl, function(data) {
                output.innerHTML = "IN THE FUNCTION";
        });

        output.innerHTML = 'END load';
    }
```

In mu output div I can see 'in the load' so it stops at the .getJSON part. 
I've included the right jquery libraries (jquery mobile and jquery1.4) and the json from the specified url validates.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

In chrome it works sigh.
I was testing it in Eclipse web browser since I'm working for an Android application.
Apperantly that browser s**ks.

Thx for the idea Sir Troll

=> still can't answer my own question

Comment: are you sure you're echoing the return in json format using something like `json_encode()`?

Comment: scratch that, just followed the link and it looks to be json format

Comment: Also, I always use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate the json.

Comment: Does Chrome/IE F12 or firebug report anything wrong?

Comment: In chrome it works sigh.
I was testing it in Eclipse web browser since I'm working for an Android application.
Apperantly that browser s**ks.

Thx for the idea Sir Troll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're not getting the data? Your example would most likely overwrite END load with IN THE FUNCTION, since the callback will be executed after the function finishes.

So output.innerHTML would get the values like this:

```
1. "in the load".
--> Ajax request start
2. "end load"
--> Ajax request finishes
3. "in the function"
```

I would suggest trying to output `data` in the callback, and remove the innerHTML changes from outside the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late in answering this but was working on `phonegap` and had similar issue. You would need to add the URL in your **phonegap.plist** file under `ExternalHost` Array.

I added that and I am now getting JSON data from an external URL.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is the jsonUrl in the same domain as your script? I'm not really sure, but I think you cannot do cross-domain requests with AJAX scripts.

Update:

Is the php script sending json headers?
`header('Content-type: application/json')`